# If list X element is present on list Y, slice list X before its position

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, indexing

**TL;DR**: Need to slice data on list A where the element is present on list B too.

Hi, I am trying to compare data I am receiving from an HTTP GET request.

The first list is called SUBJECTS which I have the list of all subjects offered to my course. The second list os called DETAILS which I have some details about every one of these subjects, including their names. Both lists are in the same order. NOTE: Some subjects can offer more than one class. Input and output example at the end of the post.

My problem here is that I need to pinpoint and separate the data from each subject to send to my DB. I thought about comparing both lists and save the index when the subject names show up but I couldn't get it right.

Here is one of the codes I tried so far:

```
def format(details, subject):
    indexes = []
    x = details
    indices = [details.index(x) for x in subject]
    enum = list(enumerate(indexes))
    for i in range(enum[0][1], enum[-1][1]):
        if i in enum[:][1]:
            print("\n\n")
        print(details[enum[i][1]], end=" ")
```

I hope I was clear enough. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

**Example input data**:

```
SUBJECT = ['EPRI02 - ADMINISTRAÇÃO', 'ECAI06.1 - AUTOMAÇÃO DE SISTEMAS INDUSTRIAIS I', 'ECA022.2 - Automação e Supervisão de Processos II (Prática)']

DETAILS = ['EPRI02 - ADMINISTRAÇÃO', '2018.1', 'IGOR AZEVEDO DOS SANTOS CITTY ROSA (32h)', 'REGULAR', 'Presencial', 'ABERTA', '6T45', 'Anexo 1 - Sala 5', '90/91 alunos', 
'ECAI06.1 - AUTOMAÇÃO DE SISTEMAS INDUSTRIAIS I', '2018.1', 'LUIZ FELIPE PUGLIESE (32h)', 'REGULAR', 'Presencial', 'ABERTA', '6M45', 'Anexo 3 - Sala 11', '13/24 alunos', 
'ECA022.2 - Automação e Supervisão de Processos II (Prática)', '2018.1', 'LUIZ FELIPE PUGLIESE (32h)', 'REGULAR', 'Presencial', 'ABERTA', '5M23', 'Prédio 2 - Sala 2211', '9/12 alunos', '2018.1', 'LUIZ FELIPE PUGLIESE (32h)', 'REGULAR', 'Presencial', 'ABERTA', '5T12', 'Prédio 2 - Sala 2211', '11/12 alunos']
```

**Example output data**:

```
SUBJECT1 = ['EPRI02 - ADMINISTRAÇÃO', '2018.1', 'IGOR AZEVEDO DOS SANTOS CITTY ROSA (32h)', 'REGULAR', 'Presencial', 'ABERTA', '6T45', 'Anexo 1 - Sala 5', '90/91 alunos']

SUBJECT2 = ['ECAI06.1 - AUTOMAÇÃO DE SISTEMAS INDUSTRIAIS I', '2018.1', 'LUIZ FELIPE PUGLIESE (32h)', 'REGULAR', 'Presencial', 'ABERTA', '6M45', 'Anexo 3 - Sala 11', '13/24 alunos']

SUBJECT3 = ['ECA022.2 - Automação e Supervisão de Processos II (Prática)', '2018.1', 'LUIZ FELIPE PUGLIESE (32h)', 'REGULAR', 'Presencial', 'ABERTA', '5M23', 'Prédio 2 - Sala 2211', '9/12 alunos', '2018.1', 'LUIZ FELIPE PUGLIESE (32h)', 'REGULAR', 'Presencial', 'ABERTA', '5T12', 'Prédio 2 - Sala 2211', '11/12 alunos']
```

Comment: Instead of showing us that pastebin, can you make a minimal example that shows your problem (basically using small data). Then, show us the expected output too.

Comment: You are right! I just edited and added some example input and output. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to organise your data is to use `collections.defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

SUBJECT = ['EPRI02 - ADMINISTRAÇÃO', 'ECAI06.1 - AUTOMAÇÃO DE SISTEMAS INDUSTRIAIS I', 'ECA022.2 - Automação e Supervisão de Processos II (Prática)']

DETAILS = ['EPRI02 - ADMINISTRAÇÃO', '2018.1', 'IGOR AZEVEDO DOS SANTOS CITTY ROSA (32h)', 'REGULAR', 'Presencial', 'ABERTA', '6T45', 'Anexo 1 - Sala 5', '90/91 alunos', 
'ECAI06.1 - AUTOMAÇÃO DE SISTEMAS INDUSTRIAIS I', '2018.1', 'LUIZ FELIPE PUGLIESE (32h)', 'REGULAR', 'Presencial', 'ABERTA', '6M45', 'Anexo 3 - Sala 11', '13/24 alunos', 
'ECA022.2 - Automação e Supervisão de Processos II (Prática)', '2018.1', 'LUIZ FELIPE PUGLIESE (32h)', 'REGULAR', 'Presencial', 'ABERTA', '5M23', 'Prédio 2 - Sala 2211', '9/12 alunos', '2018.1', 'LUIZ FELIPE PUGLIESE (32h)', 'REGULAR', 'Presencial', 'ABERTA', '5T12', 'Prédio 2 - Sala 2211', '11/12 alunos']

d = defaultdict(list)
subjects = set(SUBJECT)

for item in DETAILS:
    if item in subjects:
        current_item = item
    else:
        d[current_item].append(item)
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'EPRI02 - ADMINISTRAÇÃO': ['2018.1', 'IGOR AZEVEDO DOS SANTOS CITTY ROSA (32h)', 'REGULAR', 'Presencial', 'ABERTA', '6T45', 'Anexo 1 - Sala 5', '90/91 alunos'],
                             'ECAI06.1 - AUTOMAÇÃO DE SISTEMAS INDUSTRIAIS I': ['2018.1', 'LUIZ FELIPE PUGLIESE (32h)', 'REGULAR', 'Presencial', 'ABERTA', '6M45', 'Anexo 3 - Sala 11', '13/24 alunos'],
                             'ECA022.2 - Automação e Supervisão de Processos II (Prática)': ['2018.1', 'LUIZ FELIPE PUGLIESE (32h)', 'REGULAR', 'Presencial', 'ABERTA', '5M23', 'Prédio 2 - Sala 2211', '9/12 alunos', '2018.1', 'LUIZ FELIPE PUGLIESE (32h)', 'REGULAR', 'Presencial', 'ABERTA', '5T12', 'Prédio 2 - Sala 2211', '11/12 alunos']})
```

You can then easily access DETAILS relating to a specific subject via the standard dictionary notation.

The benefit of using a dictionary is you are not tied to maintaining index mappings. To add another related detail to a subject, you can just do `d['BAC024 - MATEMÁTICA VI'].append('Presencial')`.

Comment: Hi jpp, I thought about using dict but it can just store 1 detail per key, right? In this case, I need to store somewhat around 3 info about each subject to display my data correctly. I just edited and added some example input and output to the post. See if it becomes clearer. Thanks btw

Comment: No, the whole point of `defaultdict(list)` is that the values are lists and can store an arbitrary number of entries. But your updated data is helpful. I will update.

Comment: OMG! You are a GENIOUS! hahahah Thanks, man! It worked flawlessly!!